# How to skip a specified time in a recurring task？

Tags: hangfire

hi， I have a task that is executed hourly，but，I do not want to perform at night(such as 00:00-07:00)，what should I do?
sample code：

```
  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(nameof(SyncArticles), () => SyncArticles(), Cron.HourInterval(1), TimeZoneInfo.Local)
```

"SyncArticles" Will be executed every hour，however，remote data is not updated at night,so,i hope that this task will not be performed at night or for a specified time period,may I ask how to do it?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a text cron expression to create whatever custom interval you need.

Eg:

```
Should run every hour between and including 7am to 11pm:
"0 7-23 * * *"
```

Or:

```
If you wanted to include midnight as well:
"0 0,7-23 * * *"
```

I haven't tested these in Hangfire specifically but they are valid and should work.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for more information.